# How can I make Photoshop not change colors on export?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, export, png, color-reproduction

I have a color `#840608` somewhere on my web page and it is coded as `#840608` by HTML and it displays as `#840608` by all browsers plus it is recognized as `#840608` by screen analyzing utilities.

Now in Photoshop I am creating image, and make rectangle there. I am painting this rectangle with `#840608` color. It is displayed as `#840608` by eyedropper tool.

When I export it as a PNG the color turns to `#920203`.

How can I make Photoshop keep it's creative potential inside and be just a computer program?

Comment: Use "pngcheck -v file.png" to see if PhotoShop has inserted color management chunks (iCCP, sRGB, gAMA, and/or cHRM)

Comment: Are you sure your color mode between the native PSD document and the outputted PNG are the same?

Comment: @Aibrean I am creating documents from scratch. How to force PSD document and outputted PNG have same color mode (both now, and always, and to ages of ages)?

Answer (score 3):

→ on creating a new document / use Adobe RGB (1998) color profile or convert to it

→ PNG export in Photoshop: be sure to disable on the  `save for web`   screen  `convert to sRGB`

**Synchronize color settings across Adobe applications**

If you use Adobe Creative Suite, you can use Adobe Bridge to automatically synchronize color settings across applications. This synchronization ensures that colors look the same in all color-managed Adobe applications.

If color settings are not synchronized, a warning message appears at the top of the Color Settings dialog box in each application. Adobe recommends that you synchronize color settings before you work with new or existing documents.

Open Bridge.

Choose  `Edit > Creative SuiteColor Settings`  Select a color setting from the list, and click Apply. If none of the default settings meet your requirements, select  `Show Expanded List Of Color Setting Files`  to view additional settings. To install a custom settings file, such as a file you received from a print service provider, click  `Show Saved Color Settings Files` .